# Как создать множественную связь один-ко-многим между двумя таблицами в ACCESS

Tags: sql, ms-access

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать подобную связь?

В результате я хочу получить нарисованную связь. Просто протянуть связь не получается, т.к. ругается на целостность данных. Конкретно мне надо поставить зависимость между экземплярами "id_сети", для этого я вынес их в отдельную таблицу, но от одного ключевого атрибута я не могу поставить зависимость к составному ключу второй таблицы.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Comment: Очень странная, на мой взгляд таблица "Поставщик_покупатель". Она одновременно содержит как информацию о сущностях, так и связь этих сущностей. А Вы хотите эти пары еще и к сетям привязать? Я бы серьёзно задумался над архитектурой и над нормальной формой такой БД. Но если, хотите все-таки связать, то в этой таблице надо добавить поле "id_сети_ref" как ссылку (вторичный ключ) на "Id_сети"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо за помощь, но решение проблемы оказалось куда проще!) Надо связываемую таблицу вынести в поле два раза(причем ACCESS назовет её с пометкой "_1") и каждую из них связать с различными атрибутами. Пример на картинке...[image: введите сюда описание изображения]